# How Could i get image from parse using android with parsequery.findInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask, parse-platform

- I require following contents:
- ParseFile from `ParseQuery.findInBackground()`
- Display it in list view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

there is a example in the Parse tutorials (MealSpoting): They use this:

```
    mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<Meal>(this, Meal.class);
    mainAdapter.setTextKey("title");
    mainAdapter.setImageKey("photo");

    // Subclass of ParseQueryAdapter
    favoritesAdapter = new FavoriteMealAdapter(this);

    // Default view is all meals
    setListAdapter(mainAdapter);
```

You can download source code [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/MealSpotting)

Comment: For Each Loop in ParseObject get PraseFile Url() Load using Picasso Library